# how to hide conversions and revenue sections in Google Analytics Reports

Tags: google-analytics

I am in a need of sharing a Google analytics access of my website to a developer and want to hide revenue and conversions sections in Google Analytics account/property/view.

any guidance how is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to share access to the report in Google analytics web application then the simple answer is you can't, access to a Google analytics account is all or nothing

you could grab the data for them through the API using a service account and design your own reports display of the data

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to give visibility to only some sections or metrics of a view. You can use API (like said to DalmTo) or more simple to provide data with an external dashboard, for example with Google Data Studio, which fetches data from your Google Analytics and shows only the ones you want to share.